# Issue sorting datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

A technique I have used for a long time to do sorting in WPF is to create a CollectionViewSource and specifying SortDescriptions, eg

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="testView">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="FirstName" Direction="Descending"></cm:SortDescription>
            <cm:SortDescription PropertyName="FamilyName"></cm:SortDescription>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
```

This has worked perfectly for everything I've thrown at it except with the DataGrid. It appears to work fine the first time through but if I change the data then the grid kills the sorting. It even kills it for other controls that use the same CollectionViewSource. I've created a sample project here

http://www.mikesdriveway.com/misc/GridSortIssue.zip

To test this issue run the project and click the Refresh Data button. Notice that the order of items changes. This only happens once, to test again stop and run the project again. Now delete the ItemsSource from the DataGrid and run the project again. This time when you click the Refresh Data button nothing happens, this means the sorting remains the same. Somehow the grid is killing the sorting in the CollectionViewSource. Is this a bug?

Cheers,
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is rather odd, from what i can tell the `SortDescription` of the underlying `View` get cleared out when the source is changed, so if the `SortDescriptions` of the CVS are not re-applied there is no sorting anymore.

One workaround would be to "reset" the `SortDescriptions`:

```cs
var cvs = (CollectionViewSource)Resources["testView"];
var descriptions = cvs.SortDescriptions.ToArray();
cvs.SortDescriptions.Clear();
foreach (var descripton in descriptions) cvs.SortDescriptions.Add(descripton);
```

Comment: While not perfect this is a pretty good workaround. I have implemented this and it is working, thank you. <Rant>MS appear to make a rubbish grid in order to keep third party grid manufacturers afloat. Unfortunately these third parties also make rubbish grids so we end up with little option</rant> Btw, the sort descriptions don't get cleared out they still remain but stop functioning for some reason.

Comment: @MikeKulls: I wouldn't say that, of course nothing is perfect, but so far i haven't had much trouble with the default WPF controls, then again i didn't have exotic requirements that other people often seem to have.

Comment: @MikeKulls: No, they do get cleared out, i was talking about the `SortDescriptions` of the underlying `View`, i.e. `CollectionViewSource.View.SortDescriptions`.

Comment: I think most of the WPF controls are excellent except the grid. It feels buggy and incomplete to me. With regards to the SortDescriptions that make sense, they are cleared from the View but remain in the CollectionViewSource. It looks like the grid must have some code that clears them out possibly something to do with allowing sorting by clicking on columns (although this is off by default I believe).